# Given points on a 3d function, f(x,y,z), and sampling points x,y find z where the function exists

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, numpy-ndarray

I have the function values at a set of 3d points i.e. I know `f(x,y,z)`. Now I want to sample this function at a different set of points `(x',y')`. But I don't know the third coordinate `z'`. I need to first find the values of `z'` where the function exists (not `nan`) for every point `(x',y')` and then find the value of the function at this point i.e. `f(x',y',z')`. My code is in python. I tried using `scipy.interpolate.griddata()` but I need to give a grid of `z'` values as well. And hence I'm stuck. Is it possible to do this? If yes, how? Any other suggestions are also appreciated

```
import numpy
import scipy.interpolate
image = numpy.array([[246,  50, 101], [116,   1, 113], [187, 110,  64]])
depth = numpy.array([[5, 3, 5], [20, 25, 3], [45, 23, 11]])
height, width = image.shape
iy = numpy.array([[1.5, 0.2, 2.3], [1.6, 0.1, 2.8], [2.4, 2.6, 2.5]])
ix = numpy.array([[0.1, 2.1, 1.7], [1.2, 2.3, 0.7], [0.1, 1.9, 2.7]])
indices = numpy.stack([ix, iy, depth], axis=2)
y1 = numpy.array(range(height))
x1 = numpy.array(range(width))

# Find z1 such that image(y1,x1,z1) exists.
```

**Relation between variables in code and in problem description**

1. `f(x,y,z)` is the `image` variable
2. `(x,y,z)` is `indices`
3. Thus `f(indices[1,0,0],indices[1,0,1],indices[1,0,2]) = image[1,0]`
4. `(x',y',z')` is `(x1,y1,z1)`. I want to find `z1` such that `image[y1,x1] = f(indices[y1,x1,0],indices[y1,x1,1],indices[y1,x1,2])` exists.

Comment: Seems interesting. Please correlate between your terms in the prose (`f`, `x`, `y`, `z`, `x'`, `y'`), and the variables in the code better. I am having trouble figuring out which is which.

Comment: Damn! Sorry, that is indeed unclear. I've added the relation between the variables. Hope this is better. Please let me know if something is still not clear. Thanks for looking at this question :)

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but in your image array, you define the valid elements and their coordinates for each given image, right?  If so why can't you just do a foreach on this array and match the first two known coordinate that the loop returns, thus giving you the third coordinate and the matching image value?  This isn't so much a math problem as a search problem, and a little brute force should be helpful here, if not quite as elegant as a math solution.  Just a thought.

Comment: To speed things up, do a sort and binary search

Comment: You really shouldn't put "edit" into your edits. Your question should be a standalone work. We can see the edits in the edit history, in case someone is interested in a crappier version of your question.

Comment: Why are you using multidimensional arrays for this stuff? I feel like you're massively overcomplicating this, but it's too late, so I'll look at it in the morning.

Comment: @Symfony-Wonderer I didn't understand your solution properly. Can you please elaborate? Just to reiterate, `x'` and `x` will be different. It's like there is a surface in 3D space. I know certain points on this surface. I need to find some other points for which only 2 coordinates are known. So, I need to interpolate as well. Secondly, using foreach or any brute-force methods will be extremely slow and I can't afford that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for the comments. I resorted to multi-dimension arrays in hope of vectorizing the entire procedure. If you think that's unnecessary and can show me how I can do this without multi dimensional arrays. it would really help me a lot. Also, I found an alternate solution (there is a open source software, MPEG-RVS, that does exactly what I want to achieve). I'm not actively looking at this problem. I'm just trying to say that you need not spend a lot of time if you have other higher priority things. Nonetheless, a solution to this will be useful, in future, and for others too.

Comment: No problem, I just thought if you were to perhaps use the first two indices, you could find the subset of coordinates that had the first two by creating an array with the first two coordinates as indices, then you don't actually have to do the searching.  Then the results would be a another array that used the z coordinate as it's index and the corresponding value for each x, y, and z input.  If this doesn't sound right then I probably don't understand what you need.  Alternatively, If there are a lot of images, then you could put them in a database and use the three coordinates as indices

Comment: Cool. If I understand your statement correctly, this won't handle interpolation right? I mean, if I know the image values at `(1.1, 2.4, 5), (2.3, 1.7, 6)` and I want the image value at `(2,2)`, I'll have to interpolate. Would your solution work in this case? (If yes, then I still haven't understood your solution :/)